# Expansion in Make variables

Tags: variables, makefile, autotools, automake

I have two variables in my Makefile:

```
archs = i386 x86_64
tarball = foo-i386 foo-x86_64
```

As you see my second variable is actually based on the first one. But i want something like a regex expansion to use the first variable, like:

```
tarball = foo-$(archs)
```

But it doesn't work this way. This expands in GNU Make to:

```
tarball = foo-i386 x86_64
```

What's the best way to assign the `tarball` variable which uses my `archs` variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can rely on GNU make, the `foreach` function is your friend.

If not, the construction

```
tarball = $(archs:%=foo-%)
```

works on *some* other make's as well. However, it's still on the [non-compatible list](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Features) of features.

Comment: Wouldn't the `addprefix` function be much easier than `foreach`?

Comment: @eriktous: "Much" depends on your definition of much. I don't bother to remember addprefix and addsuffix, since $(foreach %,%-foo,) does the same job.